# UISearchBar: displaying search history

Tags: iphone, xcode, uisearchbar, bookmarks

I'd like to show search history when the bookmark button is tapped:A table with last 10 search entries would pop down below the searchbar.(like google autocomplete)

I've got search history `NSMutableArray` with `NSString` search entries.

How should I dynamically call out that list?

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

delegate for the `UISearchBar` in your file. And in this method, add the code to show a popup view containing the `UITableView` which is having the history list.

Make sure your have written `searchBar.delegate = self` in your `.m` file.

Comment: thanks, but the question is actually is how to neatly implement that popup tableview